# How can one implement the following without switch, if or any conditional operator?

Tags: java

implement the following without switch, if or any conditional operator:

```
public static createBoolean make(boolean c){
  if (c){
  return isTrue;
  }
  else{
    return isFalse;
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the return type here?  createBoolean?  Why would you use that instead of boolean?  This snippet doesn't even look like legal Java.  Anyone who asked me this question wouldn't be worth working for.

Comment: The code is legal java, but it follows no coding convention I've ever seen

Comment: Agree with @duffymo, if I got this question I would let the interview know everything wrong with their question. Also, this isn't legal Java since the instances `isTrue` and `isFalse` are never declared and instantiated. My guess is they are `enum` value or `static` members.

Comment: The following answers used conditional operators, which cannot be used to solve the problem!

Answer (score 2):

Express it as a [ternary](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html):

```
return c ? isTrue : isFalse;
```

Notes from the question:

- Assume that `createBoolean` is a class. This name doesn't follow usual naming conventions for classes having leading uppercase, but is still legal.
- Assume that `isTrue` and `isFalse` are a static fields of type `createBoolean`. These name also don't follow usual naming conventions for a field

Comment: just curious, its calling the methods "isTrue" and "isFalse", would that make any difference?

Comment: Also, isn't "?" a conditional operator, if so, then it cannot be used as a solution!!

Comment: Java ternary is this syntax: `<condition> ? resultIfTrue : resultIfFalse`

Comment: I understand its a ternary, but "?" is a conditional operator.
In other words, your solution only shorthanded the original code

Comment: `?` is not a *conditional* operator: It is the *ternary* operator. Conditional operators are: `< > == != <= >=`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the boolean operators:

```
return ! ! c;
```

Or:

```
return c && c;
```

Comment: Question is tagged with "java" not with a weak typed language.

Comment: Also, isn't "?" a conditional operator, if so, then it cannot be used as a solution!!